# regex curly braces pattern replace PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm having this issue cause I'm bad with regex, I would appreciate any help. I have the following case

```
 $text = "This is my string and I {want} to change {this}";
```

Basically I want to replace {want} and {this}, I thought I could use something like:

```
 $patterns = array();
 $patterns[0] = "{want}";
 $patterns[1] = "{this}"; 
 $replacement = array();
 $replacement[0] = "don't";
 $replacement[1] = "that";

 $new = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

So my output would be "This is my string and I don't want to change that"

Any help?

Comment: This site is good for building/testing regex: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace` uses a regular expression with delimiters and possibly modifiers.  For what you are doing use `str_replace`:

```
$new = str_replace($patterns, $replacement, $text);
```

Comment: str_replace takes out the curly braces?

Comment: Only if you do not include them in your replacement text.

Comment: If they are in the search string as you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace instead of pre_replace.

```
$new = str_replace($patterns, $replacement, $text);
```